# Nginx 1.14 can't access System Environment Variables

Tags: nginx, environment-variables

I have spend past 2 days trying to figure out how to get a System Environment Variable to get passed into Nginx.

1. I have declared the Environment Variable in `/etc/nginx.conf` with `env FOO`.
2. I have tried `perl_set` and `set_by_lua`.

But non works.

I am running this on a Ubuntu "Bionic" 18.04 machine.

Any idea?

Edit:

The issue is, Nginx strips all the environment variables, so they are not available within the web server process. Following some Nginx tutorials, `set_by_perl` or `set_by_lua` are the ways recommended for getting System Environment Variables into the web server process, which doesn't seem to work in my case.

Edit: Following is the tutorial I followed: https://web.archive.org/web/20170712003702/https://docs.apitools.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an environment variable from within nginx.conf. It will be ignored, which is what you've seen.

There are several places you can set the environment variables, I'll show the example for the file where the env vars will be availbale to all user logins and to NGINX.

> $sudo nano /etc/environment

Add your defs to the end of the file; Leave everything that is there, there. Just append your new defs. Do this exactly, no extra spaces at the end of lines, no extra lines at the end of the file. Use double quotes. No comments. Very exact.

```
export COMPILERKEY = "jk8894085349058jjggl"
export FOO="ThisIsFooValue"
export FOO2="ThisIsFooValue2"
```

Save the file

Reboot server

To show all env vars that are defined

> $env

Once defined, then you can access env vars through defined means. Access methods for the environment variables is a question which I think you're not asking about yet. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the Environment Variables themselves are already defined (`echo $FOO` returns the expected value.).

The issue is, Nginx strips all the environment variables, so they are not available within the web server process. Following some Nginx tutorials, `set_by_perl` or `set_by_lua` are the ways recommended for getting System Environment Variables into the web server process, which doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Okay. That wasn't clear from your question. Good luck, maybe someone else will come along with an answer.

Comment: Thanks @elvn, I updated the question with those information. :)